# Weekly period in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Is there a way to define the weekly period I would like to use on a report, Currently Access has the week defined as sun through sat,  I would like to use mon through sun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Weekday function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HA012289331033.aspx) has an optional parameter to define the start day - is that any use?